# How can I group/aggregate values correlated to 2 distinct values as one?

Tags: sql, oracle

So in the database there is a value in the 'value_type' column that are interchangeable with each other. When I aggregate, I want to be able to sum / aggregate the two values (A AND B) together but not the other(s) (C)? Some Sample Data is below:

```
Value_ID       Value_Tx         Value_Type
   1              5                A
   2              2                A 
   3              7                B
   4              5                C
   5              3                C
   6              1                D
   7              7                F
```

The Result I want:

```
 Sum            Value_Type
  14               A | B
  8                 C
  1                 D
  7                 F
```

I know that to sum normally I would do:

```
select sum(value)tx, value_type
  from table
 group by value_type;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you group A and B into one group? What is the actual condition/requirement? The rest seems not that hard.

Comment: yeah, A & B are essentially the 'same thing' but called different things in the database so I want to group them as 'one'. by the way why were you hoping this was homework? o.O

Comment: The other post with insert should probably be pure SQL, not PL/SQL or BULK inserts. This is why I was jokingly hoped that was your homework, not real job. As far as this one, what tells me that A and B are the same group?

Comment: yeah you aren't 100% incorrect. haha thanks a bunch by the way. And nothing, I have to make the association that they are considered 'the same value'. i.e. I want all values that are 1 and 2 in ONE group

Comment: I posted my solution - dynamic groups based on what you wrote in comments. Please take a look at the top/union all portion - this is what I call simulated data that you must prepare and post with your questions to save our time typing for you.

Comment: WHen would you recommend actually using PL/SQL over bulk inserts?

Comment: The bulk inserts done using PL/SQL. You should probably ask questions under the correct thread. In general, I would consider using pure SQL for inserts. For example, you can use CASE instead of IF... if necessary. If you must use PL/SQL then probably the best way to insert is using bulk inserts, bulk with limits... You can read about it over the weekend and watch videos. And there are tons of examples here and everywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use case expression with `group by`.

```
SELECT SUM(value_tx), 
       CASE 
         WHEN value_type IN ( 'A', 'B' ) THEN 'A | B ' 
         ELSE value_type 
       END 
FROM   t 
GROUP  BY CASE 
            WHEN value_type IN ( 'A', 'B' ) THEN 'A | B ' 
            ELSE value_type 
          END 
ORDER  BY 2;
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/96fee/3)

Answer (score 2):

```
select sum(value)tx, 'A | B' value_type
  from table where value_type  in ('A','B')

union all

select sum(value)tx, value_type
  from table where value_type not in ('A','B')
 group by value_type;
```

easy way,hope help you : )

Answer (score 1):

I have only tried my query in MySQL

```
select sum(value_tx), 
case 
   when value_type IN ('A', 'B') THEN 'A | B'
   else value_type
end as valtype
from table
group by valtype
```

Answer (score 1):

Example of how to set the groups dynamically:

```
WITH test_data AS
(
 SELECT 1 val_id, 5 val_tx, 'A' val_typ FROM dual
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 2, 2, 'A' FROM dual 
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 3, 7, 'B' FROM dual 
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 4, 5, 'C' FROM dual 
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 5, 3, 'C' FROM dual 
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 6, 1, 'D' FROM dual 
 UNION ALL
 SELECT 7, 7, 'F' FROM dual 
 )
 SELECT break_group, SUM(val_tx) total_tx, value_type FROM 
 (
  SELECT val_id, val_tx, val_typ
  , CASE WHEN dense_rnk IN (1, 2) THEN 1 ELSE (dense_rnk-1) END break_group
  , CASE WHEN dense_rnk IN (1, 2) THEN 'A|B' ELSE val_typ   END value_type
  FROM
  (
   SELECT val_id, val_tx, val_typ
        , DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY val_typ) dense_rnk 
    FROM test_data
  )
 )
 GROUP BY break_group, value_type
 ORDER BY break_group
/
```

Output:

```
 BREAK_GROUP  TOTAL_TX   VALUE_TYPE
 -----------------------------------
 1            14         A|B
 2             8          C
 3             1          D
 4             7          F
```